# how to fire two different event from the same toggle switch using php and ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

[switch off image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wS79z.png)
[switch on image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCu4C.png)
I want to make a toggle switch which needs to fire two different event from the same toggle switch using php and ajax & I have made this following html code

```html
<div id="about-btn" class="card-action">
   <div class="about-btn">
     <input type="checkbox" id="cfl" name="cfl" class="switch-input">
     <label for="cfl" class="switch-label"><h4>CFL&nbsp;<span class="toggle--on">ON</span><span class="toggle--off">OFF</span></h4></label>
   </div>
</div>
```

& following php code

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['cfl'])) {
   makeRequest('cfl_on'); // user checked the box
} else {
   makeRequest('cfl_off'); // user did not check the box
}

?>
```

this php needs to pass value to the "makeRequest()" function of my script

```
<script>
function makeRequest(actionParam){
    var request = $.ajax({
      url: "controller.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: {Action : actionParam},
      dataType: "html"
    });

    request.done(function(msg) {
        //alert(msg);
      // $("#ResponseDiv").html( msg );
    });

    request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
      alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
    });
}
```

I know I'm doing something wrong but unable to figure it out. any help will be highly appreciated. thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: You are mixing server-side script (PHP) and client-side script (JavaScript). They cannot directly call each other. You do not need php to this if all you are doing is sowing and hiding a button.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do two diferent ajax calls than:

```
$('.switch-label').on('click', function(){
    if($('#cfl').is(':checked'){
        "make ajax call 1 here"
    }
    else{
        "make ajax call 2 here"
    }
});
```

Or if you only want to hide/show your image than than just toggle the image container on click $('cfl')